# Show multilevel related data in DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a datagrid where is data of price list rows table and I use Entity Framework 6. The datagrid includes product name (Textbox), Price (Textbox) and change price (DataGridComboBoxColumn).

Price isn't a currency, it can be just 1, 2, 3 or A, B, C or something else. There is a different price categories, which is the parent of price choice table. Those two price choice examples could be "Numbers" and "Letters" as price categories. That is the main problem to get those entity related price choices to combobox for every row.

I can now get every name of price choice table to comboboxes without any relationship to price category with code below, so now I get 1, 2, 3, A, B and C. I should get 1, 2, 3 or A, B and C, depending of the products price category. **How should I get the product related data of Pricerows.Products.PriceCategory.PriceChoices to comboboxes in every row of datagrid?**

Here is a picture what I have done. Combobox should show only Numbers or Letters price category, but now it's showing all price categories. New price should be updated as a price and be shown in the price column in the datagrid.

[image]

C#:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pricerows = context.Pricelistrows.ToList();
    DataContext = this;
    pricerowsViewSource.Source = pricerows;
}
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="pricerowsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource pricerowsViewSource}}"  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Product name" Width="auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbPrice" Header="Price" ItemsSource="{Binding Products.Pricecategories.Pricechoices.Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Tables:

**Price list row**

- Price
- Product id (fk)
- Price list id (fk)

**Price list**

- Id

**Price category**

- Id
- Name

**Price choice**

- Id
- Name
- Price category id (fk)

**Product**

- Id
- Name
- Price category id (fk)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @grek40 I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Can you give an example with 2 (or some more, but not to many) datagrid rows and their expected combobox contents and what you expect to happen when a combobox item is selected?

Comment: @grek40 I added a picture with some details.

Comment: So how you determine what prices to display for a given price row?

Comment: @mm8 Price category must be chosen when new product is created at a another window. See the Product table at the end of question.

Comment: Antoher window...? This doesn't answer my question. You must somehow know what categories to display for a particular row, right?

Comment: Do you mean in the first question the `Price` or `Change price` column? @grek40 has a different way to implement the `Product` table/EF model with adding the `PriceChoiceId` as fk to `Product` table. I would guess that it's better way, but I'll take a look at it better tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with a partial answer and update if needed.

So my understanding of your requirement is the following:

1. You have a list of `Product`
2. Each `Product` has a `PriceCategory`
3. Each `PriceCategory` has a list of valid `PriceChoice`
4. Each `Product` has an optional currently selected `PriceChoice` that is required to belong to the correct `PriceCategory`

Enforcing point 4. in the database design is out of scope for this question, so I'll focus on letting the user only chose valid values in the UI but allowing any price selection on the database level.

This would be the EF model for the database to be created (not real code)

```
Product

- Id
- Name
- PriceCategoryId (fk PriceCategory)
- PriceChoiceId (optional fk PriceChoice)
- [Navigation property] PriceCategory
- [Navigation property] PriceChoice

PriceChoice

- Id
- Name
- PriceCategoryId (fk PriceCategory)
- [Navigation property] PriceCategory

PriceCategory

- Id
- Name
- [Navigation property] ICollection<PriceChoice> PriceChoices
- [Navigation property] ICollection<Product> Products
```

Whatever `Price list row` and `Price list` are supposed to be, they have no relevance to the database model as per above listed requirements.

So when working on a single `product`, the UI task to be done would be:

- Display a combobox with the selectable items `product.PriceCategory.PriceChoices`
- Store the selected item into `product.PriceChoice` (or the selected Id value into `product.PriceChoiceId`)

Feel free to ask if this is not enough structural information to solve your problem.

Regarding the problem of binding an individual ItemsSource for the comboboxes of each row:

[There is a solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20926f15-dc1c-4fc1-8450-39d16dbb5a45/datagridcombobox-with-different-itemssource-per-row?forum=wpf) involving `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle` instead of `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource`

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Price" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding PriceChoice}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <!-- Work around the requirement for static binding sources inside DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource -->
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding PriceCategory.PriceChoices}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding PriceCategory.PriceChoices}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the `PriceChoiceId` to be optional fk in `Product` model. I still think it's the more correct db design, so I guess that I should remove the `Price` field from `Price list row` table because both of them mean the same thing.

Comment: The main problem still is how to display a combobox with the selectable items from product.PriceCategory.PriceChoices

Comment: @MMakela just remembered there was this kind of *special problem* with the `DataGrid` columns... see my edit for how to use the product-specific ItemsSource for each line in the datagrid.